# C++: How to make "core" dump file being overwritten when new crash is encountered?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, overwrite, coredump

I got a simple c program to test "core dump" behavior:

$ cat 1.c

```
int main() 
{ 
   int buf[]={1,2}; 
   int j=buf[20000]+buf[30000]; 
   return 0; 
}
```

I did:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited 
$ gcc 1.c 
$ a.out
```

It generates a core file, no problem. I run "a.out" again, this time the previous "core" file was not overwritten, unless I removed the core file manually, and then a new core file is generated.

Question: how can I setup the ubuntu linux to make sure each time there's a crash, a new core dump file will overwrite the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle adding pid to core file, so every time program started with new pid core name will have new pid as 'extension'

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid
```

also, read [this](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/) with much more details

Comment: This /proc/xxx file seems to be read only, even root cannot change it. Should change /etc/sysctl.conf and add one line as : kernel.core_pattern=core.%e.%p.%h.%t, where "%e" means "executable name", "%p" means pid, "%h" means host name and "%t" means timestamp